# Uniqueness of invariant factors in finite abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group; express it as direct sum of cyclic groups of order $1<m_1,m_2,\cdots,m_r$ such that $m_i|m_{i+1}$.

Suppose $G$ is also direct sum of cyclic group of order $1<n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_s$ with $n_i|n_{i+1}$.

To show that the invariant factor (multi)sets $(m_1,\cdots, m_r)$ and $(n_1,\cdots,n_s)$ are same, is it *necessary* to go to primary decomposition of the integers involved?

In other words, we are transforming invariant-factor decomposition into primary decomposition, and concluding uniqueness of invariant factors; is it the only way to prove this uniqueness?

For example abelian groups with invariant factors $(3,6,24,48)$ and $(3,12,12,48)$ are not isomorphic; how could we proceed? (I mean, is it necessary to consider the primes $2,3$ and their totality, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that abelian groups $A, B$ with invariant factors $(3, 6, 24, 48)$ and $(3, 12, 12, 48)$ are not isomorphic, you look at $A/12A$ and $B/12B$. I think this gives you an idea how to generalize. In particular we do not need to look at prime factors over the $m_i,n_j$ involved.

Comment: there is a typo 28 should be 48.